# How to read a data file in R from Azure data lake (storage account)

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I am able to upload and download data file in Azure ML RStudio from Azure data lake (storage account) using AzureAuth and AzureStor packages with service principal Authentication.

I want to read a data file in Azure ML RStudio from Azure data lake (storage account).

Answer (score 0):

Here is code snippet for read data file in Azure ML Rstudio:

```
# Install the AzureAuth and AzureStor packages
install.packages("AzureAuth")
install.packages("AzureStor")

# Load the AzureAuth and AzureStor packages
library(AzureAuth)
library(AzureStor)

# Authenticate with your Azure subscription using a service principal
azure_auth(tenant_id = "<your-tenant-id>",
           client_id = "<your-client-id>",
           client_secret = "<your-client-secret>")

# Connect to your Azure data lake (storage account)
azure_storage_account_name <- "<your-storage-account-name>"
azure_storage_account_key <- "<your-storage-account-key>"
azure_storage_account_container <- "<your-storage-account-container>"
azure_storage_account_file_path <- "<your-storage-account-file-path>"

azure_storage_account_connection <- AzureStor::az_storage_account(
  account_name = azure_storage_account_name,
  account_key = azure_storage_account_key
)

# Read the data file from Azure data lake (storage account)
data <- AzureStor::az_blob_download(
  connection = azure_storage_account_connection,
  container = azure_storage_account_container,
  file_path = azure_storage_account_file_path
)
```